# Props can't pass multiple data with v-bind

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

```html
<div id="expense-page>    
  <div class="balance" v-for="item in Object.keys(balance)">
    <span class="balance-item">${ item }</span>
    <span class="currency-sign">${ currency }</span>
    <span class="balance-value">${ balance[item] }</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to move the working code above as Vue component like below:

```html
    // in html
    <balance-detail 
            v-for="item in Object.keys(balance)"
            v-bind:item="item"
            v-bind:currency="currency"
            v-bind:balance="balance" />

    <script>
    let balance = {{ balance | safe }} // from Django views
    let vm = new Vue({
                delimiters: ['${', '}'],
                el: '#expense-page',
                data: {
                    currency: balance[0].fields.currency,
                    balance: _.omit(balance[0].fields, ['user', 'currency']),
                },
                components: {
                    BalanceDetail,
                }
            })
    </script>

    // BalanceDetail.vue
    var BalanceDetail = Vue.component('balance-detail', {
        props: {
            item: String,
            currency: String,
            balance: Object,
        },
        template: '\
            <span class="balance-item">{{ item }}</span>\
            <span class="currency-sign">{{ currency }}</span>\
             <span class="balance-value">{{ balance[item] }}</span>\
        '
    })
```

But only the first span shows (i.e. the keys of balance field). I tried to remove the v-for and v-bind:item on the component instatiation, and I got only currency appears. It looks like only the first props passed to the component will be rendered. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem where only first prop is rendered because I don't wrap with outer element for all the spans. Wrapping with div solve the problem.

```
    // BalanceDetail.vue
        var BalanceDetail = Vue.component('balance-detail', {
            props: {
                item: String,
                currency: String,
                balance: Object,
            },
            template: '\
            <div>
                <span class="balance-item">{{ item }}</span>\
                <span class="currency-sign">{{ currency }}</span>\
                 <span class="balance-value">{{ balance[item] }}</span>\
            </div>
            '
        })
```